# How to run background thread as long as Forms is active?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, user-interface

In my program.cs file, the code is as follows:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    frmWizard frm = new frmWizard();
    Application.Run(frm);

    Thread th = new Thread(frm.ThreadSetCom);
    th.Start();
}
```

ThreadSetCom is a method that runs in an endless loop checking for something. I noticed that ThreadSetCom will only execute just before the WinForm appears and after i close the form. It doesn't execute while the Form is visible. Can anyone clear this up to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application.Run waits until the passed form in argument is closed. You may need to `create` and `start` the `thread` in the `load` event of the frmWizard.

```
private void frmWizard_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Thread th = new Thread(ThreadSetCom);
    th.Start(); 
}
```

Comment: Also note that thread will be still alive when you close the form.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! Anyway, can you point me to a link or perhaps a book where i can learn more about multithreading? I can't find one that is easy enough for me to understand.

Comment: I found this post regarding books for understanding multi-threading, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526520/good-book-about-threading-in-net

Answer (score 1):

Application.Run will block until you have closed the form which explains why you see this behaviour. Adil's answer will work but I believe you shouldn't be coupling your code in this way. It would be better if your Main method started up the second thread independantly of the Form Load event.

So you just need to re-arrange your code like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    frmWizard frm = new frmWizard();

    Thread th = new Thread(frm.ThreadSetCom);
    th.Start();

    Application.Run(frm);
}
```

Comment: ooh great... that i my intention too. I don't feel to good having a thread within another. Sounds a bit complicated. Thanks

Comment: You should also set th.IsBackground = true so that the process is terminated once the form is closed. Otherwise the background thread can keep running after the form has been closed.See here for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx